# Android NDK SDL2 OpenGL ES 2 shadow mapping (directional)- is it possible?

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es, shadow-mapping

Trying to utilize directional shadow mapping on OpenGL. Need to generate a depth texture that *isn't* a renderbuffer (need to be able to read from it) it future passes. Keep getting GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT (as result of glCheckFramebufferStatus) when running on Android (don't get error when running on OSX).

Here's my code:

```
 //Shadow
  //gen tex
  gl_shadow_bogus_texture_active_n = 7;
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+gl_shadow_bogus_texture_active_n);
  glGenTextures(1, &gl_shadow_bogus_texture_buff_id);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_shadow_bogus_texture_buff_id);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGB,tex_dim.x,tex_dim.y,0,GL_RGB,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,0);

  //gen depth
  gl_shadow_texture_active_n = 4;
  glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0+gl_shadow_texture_active_n);
  glGenTextures(1, &gl_shadow_texture_buff_id);
  glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_shadow_texture_buff_id);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16,1024,1024,0,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT,GL_FLOAT,0);

  glGenFramebuffers(1, &gl_shadow_framebuffer_id); //gen fb
  glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, gl_shadow_framebuffer_id); //bind fb
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_shadow_bogus_texture_buff_id, 0); //attach tex
  glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, gl_shadow_texture_buff_id, 0); //attach depth
```

note that the whole `gl_shadow_bogus_texture_buff_id` thing (the generation and binding of the color texture) is just an attempt to fill out the framebuffer, thus getting rid of the error. I don't actually care about the color data.

a further note is that the "color tex gen/bind" is not necessary on mac, and can be replaced with `glDrawBuffer(GL_NONE)` and `glReadBuffer(GL_NONE)`. But I can't compile with those in for android...

Comment: What's `gl_shadow_texture_active_n` for? Also, are you checking for other OpenGL errors?

Comment: @NicolBolas - `gl_blah_texture_active_n` is a means of me keeping track of which glActiveTexture that texture is bound to. I have few enough textures where I'm currently using a one-to-one texture_id-to-active_texture_n kind of architecture. Greatly simplifies things (though it renders the "ActiveTexture" layer of indirection redundant...). And yes- I'm checking for other OpenGL errors. They are all passing, so I left them out of sample code for readability.

Comment: "*I have few enough textures where I'm currently using a one-to-one texture_id-to-active_texture_n kind of architecture.*" That makes no sense at all. If you're creating a texture, it should only be bound for that purpose; once created, you *unbind* it.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong terminology regarding "binding". At the end of the day, I need to pass in the `uniform sampler2D blah_tex;` to my shader. The way I do this is by passing the `ActiveTexture` (a `GLuint`) into `glUniform1i`. So any texture I use *must be associated with an ActiveTexture*.  Where in certain cases, one might set the "active textures" just before a draw call that uses them, then switch them out for the next draw call that needs diff textures, I just set each texture into an activeTexture once, and never shuffle them. Is there something wrong with this line of thinking?

Comment: "*Where in certain cases, one might set the "active textures" just before a draw call that uses them,*" No, that's not "in certain cases"; that's standard behavior for *most* OpenGL applications. The reason being that your way, which keeps all textures bounds and has you changing uniforms, limits the number of textures you can have around to the number of available texture image units. Texture binding points are supposed to be ephemeral; you set them as needed, and unset them once they are no longer needed. Maybe that works for small examples, but not for any programs of significance.

Comment: which exactly justified my "I have few enough textures ..." statement, and reinforced my expressed model describing this layer of indirection... Your comment of "That makes no sense at all" and general aggressive tone is unhelpful and, well, bizarre. What do you want from me?

Comment: From you? I expect nothing. What I would like is for everyone reading your code to know that it is not an example of good programming practices for OpenGL. You may or may not agree with this assessment, but I don't want anyone to get the idea that using texture units as *storage* for texture objects is in common use or is a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a stencil attachment, which is likely why you've getting a `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT` error. Although not explicitly stated in the spec, most drivers require a stencil attachment when a depth attachment is also present. However, depending on the implementation, you may run into problems, because using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` with a stencil attachment may not be a supported combination (in fact, in my experience, it usually isn't). Each driver is only required to support at least one combination - unfortunately, there's no way to query exactly what the combination might be. You basically just have to guess and hope it succeeds.

The majority of Android implementations support the [packed depth stencil format DEPTH24_STENCIL8_OES](https://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/extensions/OES/OES_packed_depth_stencil.txt), and the extension implicitly supports the depth being a texture which can be sampled. You will likely have considerably more success using it (but success is not guarateed!).

Comment: Ah. Right on. The solution for me was just using `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` rather than `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16` to let it pick whatever is available. I didn't need to create/attach a stencil buffer. Would you recommend that I do anyways for compatibility purposes? Or does the "just depth attachment" functioning here imply it probably will elsewhere?